# Create multiple tasks for select value in multiple dropdown list value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a requirement where i have to create number of tasks which will be equal to number of value i select in multiselect dropdown ?

suppose for T1 if i have selcted ,Y1,Y2,Y3 it should create three task Y1 Task Y2 Task,and Y3 Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a workflow as below:

[image]

Add other options with If condition.